# Facebook JS SDK - Does photo album exist? - create album only once

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, actionscript-3

I've got a Flash App using JS in HTML to communicate with Facebook. I want to occasionally add photos to a single album so, I would like to know how to detect if a Facebook Photo Album exists so I don't create it again?
I can create photos and create Albums. Here's a cut down of my Create code (it might help):

```
function myFB_CreateAlbum()
    {
        var album_details = {
            message: "I am the album desc - test 2",
            name: "Some Name" };

        FB.api('/me/albums', 'post', album_details,  function(response){...}
```

With Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Permissions required:**

For fetching the albums/photos: `user_photos`

For posting albums/photos: `publish_stream`

---

> How to detect if a Facebook Photo Album exists so I don't create it again?

Make a `GET` request to `/me/albums`. You'll get the list of the albums, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums)

Then you can check whether or not the album already exists using the `Album ID`

**Note:** You can save the Album ID as the *response* when you create an album